# Cannot create and run Bluemix container, Unathorized

Tags: cloud, docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I followed the [official instructions](http://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/Containers/index.html#container) and also double checked with [these instructions](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/1ba56fe3-efad-432f-a1ab-58ba3910b073/entry/ibm_containers_on_bluemix_quickstart?lang=en).
1. I authenticated using
`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys myKey` command.
2. I was able to push using
`sudo ice --local push registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/myAccount/myApp`.

However when I try to create and run the container I get the following error:

```
user@comp:~$ sudo ice run --name myApp registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net/myAccount/myApp:latest
Target is container cloud. Invoking cloud service...
Command failed with container cloud service
Unauthorized... Try to login again...
```

I also get the same error when running this commands:

```
sudo ice ps
sudo ice images
```

UPDATE 1:
When I have container running I get following error:

```
:~$ sudo ice ip request
Target is container cloud. Invoking cloud service...
Command failed with container cloud service
Error requesting new floating ip
```

While `ice ip list` returns a list of 2 IP addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run ice login? ​

```
sudo ice login -k  077179b63616a6d052233dfe2ca66952e77ef0ee1de1a5fd \
-H https://api-ice.ng.bluemix.net/v1.0/containers \
-R registry-ice.ng.bluemix.net
```

After that you should be able to run `sudo ice images`.

Comment: Thanks, I missed this step when connecting the second time.

Comment: But now that I am logged in and my container is running, the command "ice ip request" results in error, while other commands work fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: I get "Command failed with container cloud service; Error requesting new floating ip". By the way I want a static IP, not floating. Am I using wrong command?

Comment: So the floating IP is just means its a sharable public IP.  Once you associate it with your app it basically becomes static, but if you release it someone else could grab it.  Also do you have docker on your path?  Can you run docker locally?

Comment: Yep, I can run docker just by typing "docker".

Answer (score 1):

There currently is an issue with the `ice ip request` command that returns an error code when infact the command it worked.  Run `ice ip list` and it will show you your IP's.  We are working on a fix for the erroneous error code.

Comment: If you want I can split the questions into 2. But I think it is fine the way it is right now.

Comment: This issue will be fixed tomorrow in production!